# Sample Population Estimation, Hypothesis Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, survey, proportion

Completely lost on where to even begin with the below question. Any help is appreciated. What formula for estimating sample size for a proportion problem would be applicable? If needed, the population of Rutgers students is 50,200. Thanks

*note: we are not supposed to go out and actually survey people; this is purely hypothetical and formula-based.

Christine claims that about 60% of students at Rutgers support dialogue among civilizations. You are going to test her claim at the 0.05 level of significance. Randomly sample of a group of Rutgers students and record their opinion. Use this sample data to test Christine's claim. Provide the information:

a) How many students did you include in your sample? Why did you choose this sample size?

b) What type of sampling did you use, and how did you obtain your sample? Was the sample truly random?

c) Test Christine's claim and if it's valid or not?

d) Based on the sample data, estimate the percentage of Rutgers students who support dialogue among civilizations?

Comment: If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly

Comment: In R, one can test $H_0: p = .6$ against $H_a: p \ne .6$ using 1000 students of whom 560 say Yes using code `binom.test(560, 1000, .6)` to obtain P-value $0.011$ and 95% confidence interval $(0.529, 0.591)$ for $p.$ By using random sampling without replacement when the sample size is less than 10% of the population size you can assume the number of Yes's is binomial. What methods have you studied about determining sample size? If you will provide context of the problem and what you have tried, maybe we can give a more direct answer.